# How copy an existing object to same path Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Hi I want to copy an existing object to same path in AWS S3 and I am getting following exception

> This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption attributes

I am using Apache camel S3, how can i resolve this. After searching, i found there is a request header which we can use to replace the existing file but it is not working

```kotlin
// multiple other attempts also present, I am not sure which header will work

exchange.`in`.headers[AWS2S3Constants.METADATA] = mutableMapOf(
            "x-amz-metadata-directive" to "REPLACE",
            "x-amz-meta-directive" to "REPLACE",
            "metadata-directive" to "REPLACE",
            "MetadataDirective" to "REPLACE"
        )
```

I have logged in the request.

> Sending Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=PUT, protocol=https, host=, port=443, encodedPath=, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent, x-amz-copy-source, x-amz-meta-directive, x-amz-meta-metadata-directive, x-amz-meta-MetadataDirective, x-amz-meta-x-amz-metadata-directive], queryParameters=[])

But it is not working. how can i copy an existing object to same path without getting this error.

Comment: Why do you want to copy it to the same path? What does this achieve?

Comment: I have use case, in which i need to skip processing file on weekend. But my S3 camel consumer, auto delete files after consumption. So on weekend i am polling and copy file to same path. If i turn of auto deletion, then i need to create an idempotent consumer (which is overkill in my scenario)

Comment: Your scheduler doesn't know about the days of the week?

Comment: hmm, yeah other option is use custom scheduler. do you have any idea how to configure in Apache camel?

Comment: I have never used Camel, but you could start at https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/cron-component.html

Comment: Are you actually changing anything to do with the copied object? You need to change *something* e.g. file name? Please add the request & current code to the question.

Comment: ok. let me try suffix filename with timestamp

Comment: works after updating filename with timestamp. but i have notice with aws-cli i was able to copy file same path
aws s3 cp <path> <same-path> --metadata-directive REPLACE
any idea @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: in aws doc it clearly say we can do that
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html

Answer (score 1):

I end up changing the filename by suffixing it with a timestamp. Now I am no longer getting the error.

But I think, there should be some way to copy existing objects via API, since I am able to do same via aws-cli

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the copyObject operation in the Apache Camel AWS2 S3 component? https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/aws2-s3-component.html#_s3_producer_operation_examples

There is an example related to headers needed to make the Copy Object operation works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sourceBucket = '*** Your Source Bucket Name ***';
$sourceKeyname = '*** Your Source Object Key ***';
$targetBucket = '*** Your Target Bucket Name ***';

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1'
]);

// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject([
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => "{$sourceKeyname}-copy",
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
]);
```